# Getting error while using composition-api in my vue js code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am a newbie to vue js learning from vue mastery tutorial and in the concept of composition-api there is an example specified in vuejs I tried the same but I am getting this error please help me out 
code:

```
<template>
<div>Capacity: {{ capacity }}</div>
</template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vue/composition-api/dist/vue-composition-api.umd.js"></script>

<script type="module">
    import { ref } from "/vue";
    export default{
        setup(){
            const capacity = ref(3);
            return { capacity };
        }
    };
</script>
```

error is : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@vue/composition-api". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: does changing your import to `import { ref } from "vue";` fix the issue?

Comment: @MattEllen No change same error

Comment: @MattEllen can you please help me out?

Comment: Sorry, that's the only issue I could find. Perhaps later if I get time.

Comment: So you are saying that they are no issues right? @MattEllen

Comment: I'm saying I don't know what the issue is. If there is an error message there must be an issue.

Comment: I also included the error message in my console @MattEllen